# Showing martingale for Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales

Consider the following process:

$$
at+bW_t+atW_t+bW^{2}_t
$$

For what a and b would this process be a Martingale?

I understand that this means we need to prove the following:

$$
E(at+bW_t+atW_t+bW^{2}_t|F_s) = as+bW_s+asW_s+bW^{2}_s
$$

This is what I have done thus far:

$$
E[G_t|F_{s}]=E[at+bW_t+atW_t+bW^{2}_t|F_{s}]
$$

$$
=at+bE[W_t|F_{s}]+atE[W_t|F_{s}]+bE[W^{2}_t|F_{s}]
$$

$$
=at+bW_s+atW_s+bE[W^{2}_t|F_{s}] 
$$

Following guidance from Jose, I substituted $$ E(W^{2}_t-t|F_{s})=W^{2}_s-s $$

$$ 
E[G_t|F_{s}]=E[at+bW_t+atW_t+bW^{2}_t-bt+bt|F_{s}]
$$
$$
= at+bW_s+atW_s+bt+bW^{2}_s-bs
$$

We can therefore see that for
$$
E[G_t|F_{s}]=Z_s, at+atW_s+bt=0.
$$
$$
t(a+aW_s+b)=0
$$
$$
\therefore -a(1+W_s)=b
$$

Is this correct? And is this a unique answer?

Comment: Recall $E(W_t^2 - t \mathcal{F}_s) = W_s^t - s$. Use this to get the remaining conditional expectation in your computation.

Comment: Do you mean $$ E(W^{2}_t-t|F_{s})=W^{2}_s-s $$ ?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo

Comment: Alright - managed to get this (see updated question). Am I on the right track?

Comment: Does $-a(1+W_s)=b$ have a solution $a,b$ ? Hint : Taking Jose's hint that $W_t^2-t$ is a martingale and looking at your very first equation, what choices of $a,b$ give you that martingale if there are any ? Next hint (from me): $W_t$ is also a martingale. What choices (if there are any)? You may also want to apply the Ito formula to your very first equation and figure out how $a,b$ must look like so that the $dt$-term vanishes. I suspect the answer will be that there are no such $a,b$.

Comment: I am incredibly lost here - if anyone could help I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there; you need to find values of $a,b$ such that $-a(1+W_s) = b$ for all $s \geq 0$. The left-hand side is non-constant unless $a = 0$, which forces $b = 0$. This is the only solution.